# How to add a microphone and a speaker / how to redirect audio from Huawei K3765 Usb modem to pc?

Tags: python, usb, modem, huawei-mobile-services

I recently got an Huawei K3765 to use with my projects. I unlocked the SIM the voice commands are unlocked. I can call from the Modem but I can't hear anything or talk into. I have tried to call using Huawei Mobile Partner and the call hack and that seems to work. But I am trying to call from python.

Comment: Did you check whether the modem was added as an additional audio card in your OS? If it is there you use that audio device like any other through pyaudio or whatever audio module you'd like. You set up call using AT&T and then open the modem's audio and do whatever you want.

Comment: The modem cannot be added as an additional audio card because it is an USB 3G modem.

Comment: Of course it can be added. 3G or not. But it obviously isn't. I am not familiar with the model so I do not know whether it supports audio GSM or just data flow. It should though. If there is no higher level approach to this you will have to manually send and receive GSM audio. Nasty job, but it can be done. You will need a GSM encoder/decoder library and a lot of patience. Hope somebody can help you more.

Comment: When I plug in the modem , there is a serial interface called /dev/ttyUSB2 and if I connect to that interface , call the module and I can see the text changing as I talk but I don't know how to covert that serial interface to audio

Comment: To decode GSM you can use HawkVoiceDI library. But as far as I know it doesn't have bindings for Python so you will have to write them first. For a little bit organized API to serial you can use PyLink which is built for modems on top of PySerial.

Comment: Also, go to pypi.python.org there are two modules that are specifically made to control Huawei. huawei and pyhumod. The latter seems to be able to get to GSM features of H directly. But I doubt that audio decoding is included. It should simplify matters around communication with the modem though.